# Regex to match multiple cases

Tags: regex, pcre, onigmo

I have the following examples that must match with my regex

```
1,[]
1,[0,0,0,[]]
1,[0,0,0,0,0,[]]
1,1
1
```

I came up with a simple way of matching the middle ones with `.?,\[.*\[\]\]` but it doesnt match the first and the last one.

Maybe this is too much to handle with regex but I want to check the following things:

1. If there is a ',' it should have a following character or characters(numbers or letters)
2. If a bracket is opened: it should close '[]'
3. The bracket insides can be whatever but it must respect rule 1 and 2.

I am trying to find a solution so I'm grateful if you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Something like `^\d+(?:,(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|\d+))?$`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RnlVa/1).

Comment: Condition 1 does not appear to be satisfied wherever `',['` appears in your examples. Please clarify "Bracket inside can be whatever..." by editing.

Comment: Nice one, @Wiktor. I hope you will provide an answer as there are relatively few that employ recursion. (I think you meant `+` rather than `++`.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `++` is the possessive quantifier for `+` but here it is at the wrong place, it's more efficient to make the `*` possessive `(?:[^][]+|(?1))*+` or at least to make the group atomic `(?>[^][]+|(?1))*` (that is shorter and avoid backtracking in the recursion too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d+(?:,(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|\g<1>)*])|\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RnlVa/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:,(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|\g<1>)*])|\d+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|\g<1>)*])|\d+)` - one of the alternatives:

    - `(\[(?:[^][]++|\g<1>)*])` - Group 1: `[`, then zero or more occurrences of one or more chars other than `[` and `]` or Group 1 pattern recursed
    - `|` - or
    - `\d+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.